# Is there a service like localbitcoins.com for Litecoin?

Tags: exchanges, litecoin

At the moment, I use localbitcoins.com to find people to buy bitcoins from who have bank accounts so I don't have to fund an online wallet before I can buy.  In order to sell bitcoins, yes the online wallet needs to be funded with bitcoins and that is fine.

Does such a service exist for litecoins too?  So I can find people in my chosen country to buy from, so I can transfer money to their bank account without having to find an online wallet first with money.  I would understand that if I wanted to sell litecoins, the online wallet would need litecoin funds available first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.litecoinlocal.net/ is the site you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

You can also try https://www.local-litecoin.com , supports about 257 countries, multiple local currencies and payment methods

Answer (score 1):

I have found that many people on localbitcoin.com don't just sell/buy bitcoins, but are also interested in exchanging altcoins. So you could check your local area at localbitcoin.com and with a little luck find a litecoin seller. (read the comments and terms on the user pages)